# Python multiple processes to read input and call an expensive model

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing

I have a setup with 2 functions, like this.

```
def fun1(input_stream, output_stream):
    batch_data = []
    #read input line by line and construct a batch of size batch_size
    for line in input_stream:
        batch_data.append(process(line))
        if len(batch_data) == batch_size:
            batch_results = fun2(batch_data)
            #write results line by line to output stream
        batch_data = []

def fun2(batch_data):
    # call an expensive model and return the response
    return process(expensive_call(batch_data))
```

In the setup, an external caller calls `fun1`. `fun2` is waiting to get the batch from `fun1`, and when the model is called, `fun1` is waiting idly.

My first intuition is to see if we can use multiprocessing to separate `fun1` and `fun2` into 2 processes. `fun1` keeps writing to a queue of max size (say, `batch_size * 5`) and whenever `fun2` is free, it processes whatever is available in the queue (if a full batch or more is available, reads a batch. Else, reads whatever is available.)

I am experienced in python but have never had to use multi-processing/multi-threading. What is the best way to do this in python? Will it be better to use multi-processing/multi-threading, and what is the difference?
Also, will it be a good idea to do the writing to the `output_stream` asynchronously as well?

Are there any other ways to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

I would turn function `func` into a generator function that *yields* its batches and can be used as an *iterable* to be used with either the `multiprocessing.Pool.imap` or `multiprocessing.Pool.imap_unordered` methods of the `multiprocessing.Pool` (see the code comments for the distinction). These methods allow you to do something with the final results as they become available compared with `map`, which will not return until all batches have been processed.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def fun1(input_stream, output_stream):
    batch_data = []
    #read input line by line and construct a batch of size batch_size
    for line in input_stream:
        batch_data.append(process_line(line))
        if len(batch_data) == batch_size:
            yield batch_data
        batch_data = []
    # The possibility exists (no?) that input is not a multiple of batch_size, so:
    if batch_data:
        yield batch_data

def fun2(batch_data):
    # call an expensive model and return the response
    return process(expensive_call(batch_data))

def main():
    pool = Pool()
    # The iterable, i.e. the fun1 generator function can be lazily evalulated:
    results = pool.imap(fun2, fun1(input_stream, output_stream))
    # Iterate the results from fun2 as they become available.
    # Substitute pool.imap_unordered for pool.imap if you are willing to have
    # the results returned in completion order rather than task-submission order.
    # imap_unordered can be slightly more efficient.
    for result in results:
        ... # do something with the return value from 
    
# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```